# Another challenge for you guys

Tags: cipher

Ciphertext:

> XLLDY DXLLM IQXLF WHLTQ VXEEG CKKIP VZFOT MAYYD RGFYY DLRBQ PVIQH FTUVM PIKOY LBNEY GJECN SRMBA VBXYA NESHJ HBKYS DTMLO ZGZFC SAYBH JYFLB EIYAR XHKXI ETLLY SQYCP VXLXH RWVCI HFSXQ XOHXE IEUSO LRXFK DIQHN JZEFK YGNRY LHZKK JTCIY XGKLV DRYBM JEVCG CDBIB GOFDI NHBVG IRTNJ XEKHN KYIFM IKUGY UUZXS BXWRW KLBXR BXWUY DSXCF UJOLR MUJOX SHLVN EPMHR ORYKL VDMBX GVRXD HFFBX LHWIE SEGCK XIKXW JEVNR WESEE RUDOA RTBKC VSHGL BHPTY YOZYA CUXEQ XCKSR SMLFZ TMZHZ NEPMH ZRGGK YSVPG PSEKQ PXAES VYTTR LGGMU DYPNB XVRXD HYIOL NLIDD EBXCQ XIPYY YDIQK OFMJM LLVGS NKIAK QCANE YQCAN YQYMK BKBEC UIKOV SLMVB TEGCI LRYVY NDEFM YGYLC ANESC RBFZL ERLHZ NIPNN IERCO UYCRY DFRLI FMMJY VATMK XIETS DCIGM LRZHL TMVDE RLLVV PYFMV RXLHM ZCYAH ZPWXS UQVSZ YXPRR IPNMD KMJEC NCVCP IGBSH TGVRX DHFCK WQXLX XSAXB KPSLK YTXSA XFGSG LBLGO LRLCU OZCBB TKIZM BXSQL HCKKG GYCEE WGANI OLRXB NNRYP IYPSL HCKCI SJYYD IJUCK KTKHW ESIPT YJOLR WHRCA CBPCK ZGKSE KQWKY MOVYX LVRXR TBKBI FMUID YZTYU SVYXF TKOAT FPOLR MUYDX MGMZD MEGCU KIJLC DCMRT BKCTY ALVZR MBNRM MDBHL OLRWU VVHJN IYCCR KUGRG GAQWY ECWCI KIJVI ENRYG QFBMC ANWYW LHCKS FKTFR MMRBF FZHLT FRBYR EOTNI GKUMR XGPXV NMTBX ESEKX LJOZJ XMDOL RLYKK XQGUB VEZXB KXSGM OCYWL TECKF YDYVC SFPYJ YLRWH RKMQL OIXMF MCNOM JWFLY LQKYN YTQMC WYWSV ICOLR MUYDI TXCCO FMAQV CSFMH VOARX VKSPN LSCZI CWMZD YZWYZ PMLNH VOFCO UYIPY MCUXE WGUDB IEMUY DCYPY DKWCA NESWC MUKCG GOUCC IFMYK SRSHN JWMYM HVWIT HGTSZ YEMEK TCANJ SWGKW VRXDH NLYCY PUVOW WTGVG ITXCC OFGGY YDRGE LVLXY TXEOK YXBKV SPMHF MRYVY NPMRV CCPRM VLVRX PNZDY VDXMF VSRXL FWKLB BKOQM LYMKL WXBKD EFMXV CMJTY IOZYA FCKHL TNEOR GMHFM IFMMJ YVATN GEVCR UDBEU MUYDX YXLYD KLBLV RXYZY YDICL IKXYE XVVFE FLLVG SNKIA KQCAN WYPJT MVFMJ GCKCS AKYNY PFVOD KXYWY VMGSL NYQMK RWRWS JICUP SQWIY DIKPY EBYMM UYDWG XJFRC KMMFM XYXLX DELXN WYHLT NYQYM UYIKK LBHES AFMLF GWCBL FDGGO FCKXY ANNOM TRGJS XGMOS DLENI ILRYX GPVIP NMKCY KBNRR XBBUJ NRYXG UOXAX LIYGC ALZKJ WTFGY XQBBK NMYLC EOLUG IZDYJ HMVBE PHZVZ SFHNE SKCUH RMMLB FIOFL BMJOV EGITQ RGWHV ZQGXB KDERA ALYFC UNYQM KXWRO TRTBK DGCIM FBTCA NYDMU RFCKR GYQFX RGANZ GWCBG VXIEG CKRKG YSXBI LXYCL EPXXZ CRMVX VNRCI RVOZY ACUXE JEUYO XGAQE SVYEO GYTWE FRCVC OCEER CXVKY RCOUY CHMAN VWCKL MVVIF MYEYR KXFSY VNAMZ UVSMY YDSRG IZDYJ HMEGS PNIKX IQXLG YXQKY NYTEG CUKIJ KYYDS FMCNO XYBNF QILHN ESKCU IKOPZ TYIOA CPXEY GCLXE KWCBG VXIPN IWYWC VCMBI QVCKK QMEJZ NIFMH ZRXGP EIYAR XHKXI ETLLY TMEYM OHMMY CLECK YNOAR LLZPW EGCYD SUMXV FIGAW RIEJX XJSLR MUYDJ JXMPW XPHZD YGGWH ROPZT NZFIL BYYDC YEYUY XBXEI YAQXC CVECA NXXSK THFSW SYHFM KLBQF CJMRA VDEPM MIESL HCKEP MLFRX SGMUE BIRGC EKSRX FSKRC FUVLS RZHZB ECIJR OPGAQ EYMRB MFZLQ BNZBF CANXX MQBFR XMEKU DIPCO CKMID YYUXE YBLKC YYWHR IRYFL VQRGL YZVPY KYYRX GPHFS XATLF PXPHJ GEWEG CUVMS USCDG CYLVZ HLTBI OLBXS RVTQT BRSWQ NLUOV YXZVG XYANC VELXY SCEFK UNRWG DLLDS QLOIO LR`

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please read [Code Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do): these puzzles are not any fun to solve and will likely not be well-received by solvers.

Comment: Source: [National Cipher Challenge](https://www.cipherchallenge.org/) 2018, puzzle 9B. A third-party archive has the [cipher and solution](https://github.com/themaddoctor/BritishNationalCipherChallenge/blob/master/2018/9B/).

Answer (score 4):

> Vigenère, again, with key 'TURKEY', then reverse.

This gives (upon respacing, punctuation not added):

> THE RUSSO TURKISH WAR HAS BEEN ALL THAT WE FEARED RUSSIA HAS PLAYED HER HAND PERFECTLY BUILDING SUPPORT FOR ACTION WITH HER ALLIES IN GERMANY AND AUSTRIA AND EFFECTIVELY MARGINALISING THE BRITISH POSITION WHILE APPEARING TO BE AMENABLE TO AN INTERNATIONAL SOLUTION OUR STRATEGY OF SOWING CONFUSION AMONG THE ALLIES WORKED TO DELAY THE INEVITABLE AND I COMFORT MYSELF THAT THIS DELAY ACHIEVED TWO THINGS FIRST WE WERE ABLE TO DEVELOP OUR AGENT NETWORK WITHIN THE DIPLOMATIC SERVICES OF OUR ENEMIES AND SECOND WE WERE ABLE TO BEGIN TO NEGOTIATE WITH OTHER LEADING POWERS TO PRESENT OUR OWN SOLUTION TO THE TURKISH PROBLEM NONETHELESS MY METHODS HAVE NOT BEEN UNIVERSALLY POPULAR IN WHITEHALL AND I HAVE EXPENDED CONSIDERABLE ENERGY FIGHTING ENEMIES WITHIN NOW FINALLY WITH THE PROSPECT THAT PEACE MIGHT BE BOUGHT AT THE IMPENDING CONGRESS IN BERLIN I CAN BEGIN TO HOPE FOR A RESOLUTION WHEN I SAID THIS TO PLAY FAIR HE CORRECTED ME AND SAID THAT I MUST SURELY MEAN BROUGHT BUT IT IS MY VIEW THAT ALL VICTORIES WORTH WINNING ARE BOUGHT AND OFTEN AT GREAT COST MY HOPE IS THAT OUR NEW METHODS OF DIPLOMACY MIGHT SUCCEED AT A MUCH LOWER COST IN LIVES ALL OF THE MAJOR POWERS HAVE BEGUN TO SEE THE GATHERING THREAT THAT WAR MAY ERUPT ACROSS THE CONTINENT AND ALL HAVE REALISED THAT THEY HAVE SOMETHING MORE TO LOSE FROM FURTHER CONFLICT IF WE CAN CONTROL THE AGENDA AT BERLIN THEN I BELIEVE WE MAY SEE A WAY OUT OF THE CRISIS THE PANSLAVIC MOVEMENT AIMS TO UNITE THE SLAVIC STATES IN THE SAME WAY THAT GERMANY AND ITALY HAVE BEEN UNIFIED BUT IS DEEPLY SPLIT BETWEEN THOSE WHO BELIEVE THAT THE LOCUS OF ITS POWER SHOULD LIE WITHIN RUSSIA AND THOSE WHO SEEK A BALKAN SOLUTION THE BALKAN STATES THEMSELVES REMAIN DIVIDED WITH VARIED CULTURAL AND POLITICAL AMBITIONS OF THEIR OWN AND NO CLEAR IDEA OF WHICH PARTY SHOULD LEAD THE UNIFICATION PERHAPS THAT IS MISLEADING IT IS NOT THAT THEY LACK A CLEAR IDEA BUT RATHER THAT THERE ARE VERY MANY RIVAL VIEWS AND THESE ARE INCOMPATIBLE THE QUESTION OF HOW AND WHETHER THIS UNIFICATION MIGHT BE ACHIEVED IS THE PRINCIPLE CONCERN OF THE CONGRESS ALL OF THE MAJOR POWERS WILL I AM SURE HAVE A VIEW BUT MY FOCUS IS ON THE SMALLER STATES AND PARTIES MY AGENTS ACROSS THE BALKANS HAVE NURTURED INSTABILITY IN THE HOPE THAT WE CAN BRING PRESSURE TO BEAR THROUGH THEM ON THE MAJOR POWERS OF COURSE THE FRENZIED ATMOSPHERE OF THE DIPLOMATIC BAZAAR IN GERMANY WILL BE RICH IN TRADING OPPORTUNITIES AND I HAVE HEARD RUMOURS THAT WE MAY GAIN CYPRUS CEMENTING OUR CONTROL OF THE MEDITERRANEAN TRADE ROUTES AT THE SAME TIME BY TRADING MACEDONIA BACK TO THE OTTOMAN STATE WE HOPE TO UNDERMINE RUSSIAN TERRITORIAL GAINS AND PERHAPS TO SETTLE THE BALKAN QUESTION PERMANENTLY IF SO OUR AGENT NETWORK IN BOSNIA WILL GIVE US A FOOTHOLD IN THAT REGION I WILL CONTINUE TO WORK CLOSELY WITH THEM IN THE HOPE OF CREATING A NEW AND MORE SECURE FUTURE